# Meaning of .html in react-router paths

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am maintaining a React project in which the route paths have `.html` at the end.

```
<Route name="courses" path="/courses.html"  addHandlerKey={true} handler={CourseIndexPage} />
<Route name="students" path="/students.html" addHandlerKey={true}  handler={StudentIndexPage} />
```

I need to add pages for single records and would like to have paths like this:

```
/courses/:courseId
/students/:studentId
```

If I remove the `.html` from the path my gulp build fails, because the `courses.html` and `students.html` files don't get generated in my `dist` folder.

Can someone please point me in the right direction concerning **what the `.html` is doing** and if there is a way to remove it? Perhaps a setting in `react-router`.

Is `.html` part of a methodology with react-router I can read up on?

---

UPDATE:
I think the paths look like that because this app is using server-side routing. There is a line in a `server.js` file which says `app.use(express.static('target/dist'));` which means that the pages are served from there.

I am still wondering how I would pass the ID to a new route with `.html`. Would something like `path="/students.html?id={id}` work? It seems awkward.

Comment: `/students/:studentId.html`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The info in the UPDATE is correct.

The `.html` are there because of **server-side rendering**. Each route is served from a separate `.html` file on the server through this node command:

```
app.use(express.static('target/dist'));
```